# Calling Java code from JavaScript (Spring boot)

Tags: javascript, java, url, spring-boot

This is my controller:

```js
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/test")
public class TestServlet {
    @RequestMapping("/country/{latitude}-{longitude}")
public String getCountry(@PathVariable String latitude, @PathVariable String longitude, Model  model){
//inject the data in the JSP
model.addAttribute("latitude", latitude);
model.addAttribute("longitude", longitude);
 
//return the html
return "private/private";
}
```

I want to know how to access this method with parameter from javascript code.

```js
 public String getCountry(@PathVariable String latitude, @PathVariable String longitude, Model  model);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get the result in JSON then you could change the controller as follows,

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/test")
public class TestServlet {

@ResponseBody
@RequestMapping("/country", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/json")
public Map<String, String> getCountry(@PathVariable String latitude, @PathVariable 
String longitude){

final Map<String, String> messageObject = new HashMap<>();
messageObject.put("latitude", latitude);
messageObject.put("longitude", longitude);

//return the html
return messageObject;
}
```

Then on the client side,

```
$.getJSON("/country", {latitude: <latitude>, longitude: <longitude>}, function(data) { 

        if (data != null) {
          for(key in data){
           var lat = data[latitude];
           var long = data[longitude];
          }
        }
     });
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this would do

```
 $.ajax({
     type : "GET",
     url : "http://<server>:<port>/test/country/<latitudevalue>-<longitudevalue>",
     contentType: "application/json",
     dataType: "json",
     success : function (data, status) {
        ......
     },
     error : function (status) {
        ....
     }
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

I fear that *@PathVariable* has some problems to correctly recognise variables split by *'-'*.
I'd use other standard characters for this task like *'/'* or *'&'*.

Also I'd specify the HTTP method in the @RequestMapping annotation like:

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/country/{latitude}-{longitude}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
```

The js ajax call would be something like:

```
$.ajax({
 type : "GET",
 contentType: "application/json",
 dataType: "json",
 url : "/test/country/" + lat + "-" + lon,
 success : function (data, status) {
    /*CODE*/
 },
});
```